# Javascript – event delegation on dynamically created element not working

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

Sorry for another duplicate.

I'm trying to bind a click event listener to links which will be dynamically created later. Unfortunately this doesn't work:

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("click")
    }
});
```

Strangely it also doesn't work on a link which is not created dynamically. It is however working on the `body`, but that's not the target.

I also tried `if (e.target.classList.contains("someclass")) {}`

The DOM nodes are `body->header->div->a` if that makes a difference. (?)

Thanks for any advice on how to make it work!

Comment: I think the first question here is: is your event handler triggering?  If you add `console.log('foo')` to the handler on the parent element, and click the (child) link, does it fire?  If not, there's a problem with your understanding of event delegation (and we'll likely need to see your DOM/HTML more).  If it is, there's a problem with your logic ... but the two are very different problems.

Comment: This current piece of code is working for static links https://jsbin.com/caqocogoci/edit?html,js,console,output What do you want to achieve can you share you html code as well that you are trying to work on?

Comment: @JérémieBardon nope

Comment: @JérémieBardon You should read up on how "event delegation" works (also referred to as "event bubbling").  It's very much a valid strategy to ensure your event handlers fire even on elements newly-added to the DOM.

Comment: Oh ok! Thank you very much doesn't know about that!  So i supposed it's also better for performence since we don't have to create an event listener for each input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `target`, sometimes the target is not the expected element.
See for example this code: the dynamically generated `<a>` have inner `<span>` Elements.
On click the `target` will be that `span`.

To get around that minor problem we can use the `.closest()` selector, in both cases, span or no span:

```js
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.closest('a')) { // All oyu need
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("click")
    }
});

setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector("#links").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `
    <a href="#"><span>One</span></a>
    <a href="#"><span>Two</span></a>
  `);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<header><div id="links"></div></header>
```

Comment: You're right!  Thanks! It works now. There was indeed a span element inside the link element! I didn't know about the closest() selector, it'll come in handy later again. Thanks, stay healthy!